# Can you find the infinite loop in this code?

Tags: java, loops, debugging, methods, infinite

I am new in programming. Studying from hyperskills.org.
**When scanning fill() method**, I think program executes an infinite loop. I couldn't understand the debugger module of Intellij IDEA edu.

```
package machine;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Initial Amounts
    private static int waterAmount = 400;
    private static int milkAmount = 540;
    private static int beansAmount = 120;
    private static int disposableCupAmount = 9;
    private static int moneyAmount = 550;

    //Details of Coffee Types: 0 - espresso, 1 - latte, 2 - cappuccino
    private static int coffeeTypeTemp;
    final private static int[][] coffeeDetails = {
            {0, 250, 0, 16, 4},
            {1, 350, 75, 20, 7},
            {2, 200, 100, 12, 6}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
        String action = scanner.nextLine();

        while (!action.equals("exit")) {
            switch (action) {
                case "buy":
                    buy();
                    System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
                    action = scanner.nextLine();
                    break;
                case "fill":
                    fill();
                    System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
                    action = scanner.nextLine();
                    break;
                case "take":
                    take();
                    System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
                    action = scanner.nextLine();
                    break;
                case "remaining":
                    amountOfGoods();
                    System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
                    action = scanner.nextLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

        public static void buy() {
        System.out.println("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino, back - to main menu:");
        String coffeeType = scanner.nextLine();
        // Initial amount changes according to coffee type
        switch (coffeeType) {
            case "1":
                coffeeTypeTemp = 0;
                isEnoughToMakeCoffee(coffeeTypeTemp);
                break;
            case "2":
                coffeeTypeTemp = 1;
                isEnoughToMakeCoffee(coffeeTypeTemp);
                break;
            case "3":
                coffeeTypeTemp = 2;
                isEnoughToMakeCoffee(coffeeTypeTemp);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void fill() {
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of water do you want to add:");
        int waterFill = scanner.nextInt();
        waterAmount += waterFill;
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of milk do you want to add:");
        int milkFill = scanner.nextInt();
        milkAmount += milkFill;
        System.out.println("Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add:");
        int beansFill = scanner.nextInt();
        beansAmount += beansFill;
        System.out.println("Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add:");
        int disposableCupFill = scanner.nextInt();
        disposableCupAmount += disposableCupFill;
    }

    public static void take() {
        System.out.println("I gave you $" + moneyAmount);
        moneyAmount = 0;
    }
    public static void amountOfGoods() {
        System.out.println("The coffee machine has:");
        System.out.println(waterAmount + " of water");
        System.out.println(milkAmount + " of milk");
        System.out.println(beansAmount + " of coffee beans");
        System.out.println(disposableCupAmount + " of disposable cups");
        System.out.println(moneyAmount + " of money");
    }

    public static void isEnoughToMakeCoffee(int coffeeTypeTemp) {
        if ((waterAmount - coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][1]) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, not enough water!");
        } else if((milkAmount - coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][2]) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, not enough milk!");
        } else if((beansAmount - coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][3]) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, not enough coffee beans!");
        } else if((disposableCupAmount) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, not enough disposable cups!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I have enough resources, making you a coffee!");
            remaindersOfGoods(coffeeTypeTemp);
        }
    }

    public static void remaindersOfGoods(int coffeeTypeTemp) {
        waterAmount -= coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][1];
        milkAmount -= coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][2];
        beansAmount -= coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][3];
        disposableCupAmount--;
        moneyAmount += coffeeDetails[coffeeTypeTemp][4];
    }

}
```

Comment: There are some pitfalls with the error prone Scanner, i.e. nextInt (hasNextInt!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `fill()` function reads only integers.

So let's say you have this input:

```
"fill\n1\n1\n1\n1\nexit"
```

where `\n` is newline character.

First, you call nextLine, which is correctly parsed as "fill" and the \n character is read, however it's not part of the output. Then the `fill()` is called, where you call `nextInt()` 4x. This function reads characters until it finds any number character, and keeps reading them until it hits any white-space character.

So, at first, it will read `1`, because it hits `\n`.

Then it will read `\n1` and it hits `\n` again. - so you get integer 1.

Then again, it will read `\n1` and it hits `\n` again. This will happen once more, so 1 is read 4x.

Then your function returns back to the while loop, where `nextLine()` is called.

However, this function will read all character before it hits `\n`. That means, it will only read `\n` - so the parsed input is empty, there are no characters before newline, there is no `case` for this input in your `switch`, and it's not also equal to exit, so your while loop will actually never end.

To fix it, attach `scanner.nextLine()` at the end of your `fill()` function, so the newline character is read before scanning.

*Note*: The newline character is platform dependent, it may not necessarily be `\n`.

Comment: Thank you very much, It was impossible to find the error for me I think. Now I am trying to understand what you told :)

Comment: I understood exactly. Thanks for your amazingly detailed explanation. 

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the scanner.nextLine() when your fill() method ends, or else it will read a blank space or any such character which was entered while in the fill() method.
Also, your default case has just a break, so if the action variable has any value other than what you were expecting, it will go into an infinite loop.
So put these lines in the default case too:

```
System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):");
action = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting your issue after using the fill function. This is caused due to using nextInt() not making a new line.
You can read more about this at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Replace your fill function with this.

```
public static void fill() {
    System.out.println("Write how many ml of water do you want to add:");
    int waterFill = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    waterAmount += waterFill;
    System.out.println("Write how many ml of milk do you want to add:");
    int milkFill = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    milkAmount += milkFill;
    System.out.println("Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add:");
    int beansFill = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    beansAmount += beansFill;
    System.out.println("Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add:");
    int disposableCupFill = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    disposableCupAmount += disposableCupFill;
}
```

Another solution is to simply add a scanner.nextLine() at the end of your function.